# Unit test Json String conversion

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, testng

I want to unit test a function which converts Json String to arraylist

here , i have a statement

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
```

while testing this json array is always null,

does anybody have any idea why it is null.

Here is the full code

```
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                StatementDetailObject transactiondetail = gson.fromJson(jsonArray.get(i).toString(), StatementDetailObject.class);
                if (transactiondetail.getTranType() == 0
                        || transactiondetail.getTranType() == 1) {
                    statementDetailList.add(transactiondetail);
                }
            }
```

Comment: check the value of your jsonResponse

Comment: i passed jsonResponse and i have to test whether it is converted to arraylist or not

Comment: yes, but have you checked that method gets the value you think it does?

Comment: yes it gets value and in 
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
 this line i get null value in jsonArray 
so loop wont work\

Comment: what is the type (package) of JSONArray, and what is the type of jsonResponse?